# Leopard gecko is wounded, can't move its back legs

Tags: reptiles, leopard-geckos

I have a leopard gecko. It just leaped out of my hands from four feet up and it can't move her back legs.
I live in a small town, there is nowhere to bring her. What should I do?

Comment: The condition you describe could be indicative of an urgent or emergency health issue, please contact your vet for direction on how soon your pet needs to be seen. If someone knowledgeable in first aid is available, they may be able to write an answer, but you should not wait.

Answer (score 5):

Okay, there's really nothing you can specifically do to treat your lizard since you lack the proper equipment to do any diagnosis and determine what the actual injury is. Given the lack of movement, I doubt it's a simple as a broken leg.

So, other than ensuring proper body temperature and ensuring access to food that doesn't really move (e.g. meal worms), I think your only real option is to figure out how to get her to a vet as soon as possible. Injuries that may involve broken limbs require a re-break to set properly if the bones have started knitting, so not ideal to wait very long.